# Does GPO Security Filtering need to match ANY or ALL rules in the Filter?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

**my main question is this:**

Is the security filtering for a GPO calculated using AND logic or with OR logic to apply the filters?

Here is the context of my situation for a background on why I am asking:

**OU Structure:**

```
-- Biz-Computers
---- Site1-Computers
---- Site2-Computers

-- Biz-Users
---- Management
---- Operations (GPO Applied here: "OperationsGPO")
```

I have the "OperationsGPO" applied to the "Biz-Users/Operations" OU

This GPO is a User based GPO but it only applies to a single group of users within the Operations OU, and I ONLY want to apply the GPO to the user if they are logging into a computer in "Site2-Computers" OU

Therefore I have added the required Operations users (not all of them) to a group "OpsUsers" and added the Site2 computers to a group called "Site2Comps" and I added those groups to the "Security Filtering" field of the GPO

Since there are 2 groups defined in the Security filtering ("OpsUsers" and "Site2Comps") I am not clear on how they are applied -- do BOTH parameters need to match (AND logic) or does ANY of the objects need to match (OR logic)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER TO THE QUESTION:** 
Logical **'OR'** -- the GPO will apply if *any* of the Security Filters match.

**SOLUTION TO SITUATION:**
Configure user Group Policy Loopback Processing Mode

1. Create a COMPUTER group policy under the OU of the desired computer(s)
2. Edit the new GPO and browse to:

   Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Group Policy
3. Enable "Configure user Group Policy Loopback Processing Mode" and set it to "Merge"
4. Add any USER policies you want to enable to this same COMPUTER policy (loopback makes this legal)
5. Ensure the new GPO has security filters to validate the users you want, and the computer(s) you're applying to.

The loopback basically applies a "user" policy to a specific computer.

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way as you add ACL into file/folder permission. In typical scenarios where no "deny" entry is involved, and you add multiple groups "allow", or "apply"  permissions, any of the group gets the GPO.

edit//: However, adding computers into your filtering won't help you at all because what you have is a user setting GPO. Computer account is irrelevant here. Loopback probably is more appropriate for what you want to achieve, but I am not sure if loopback on computers + user security filtering will work out your way.

Comment: "ANY of the group gets the GPO" -- so this is the answer? If so, then how would I solve my problem of applying a USER GPO to a user group but only to a certain computer OU

Comment: read your question more carefully and revised my answer. It's "OR" only when you use 2 user security groups for filtering. Adding computer group won't work on user setting GPOs.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction with the loopback, thanks. Posted the solution.